# Refer to immediate selector object with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn some jQuery, and I setup a test page with the following code:

```
<a id='encode' href='javascript: void(0)'>encode</a> |  
<a id='decode' href='javascript: void(0)'>decode</a> | 
<br/>
<textarea id='randomString' cols='100' rows='5'></textarea>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document.ready(function () {
  $('#encode').click(function() {
    $('#randomString').val(escape($('#randomString').val()));
  });
  $('#decode').click(function() {
    $('#randomString').val(unescape($('#randomString').val()));
  });     
});
</script>
```

The idea is I can put something in the textarea and click either "encode" or "decode", and it will either escape or unescape what I put into the textarea.

This code works just fine, but my question has to do with how I am changing the value of the textarea. In my code, I am selecting the textarea value twice: once to (un)escape it, and once again to change the value. IMO this seems clunky and maybe unnecessary. I thought maybe I could do something like this instead:

```
$('#randomString').val(escape(this));
```

But `this` seems to refer to the object of the link I clicked, not the `#randomString` selector, so is there some other magic word I can use to reference that `$('#randomString')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, if I understand you correctly, is no. There isn't a way to refer to `$('#randomString')` where you're talking about. It's just a parameter to the `val` method, so it's just plain JavaScript syntax, no jQuery "magic".

To accomplish the task at hand and make the code cleaner and less clunky, I would save off the jQuery object for `#randomString` so you don't have to keep creating it:

```
$(document.ready(function () {
    var $rndStr = $('#randomString');

    $('#encode').click(function() {
        $rndStr.val(escape($rndStr.val()));
    });

    $('#decode').click(function() {
        $('#rndStr').val(unescape($rndStr.val()));
    });     
});
```

Comment: Okay, this looks like same principle as ShankarSangoli's answer but you just create the object once (which I agree is cleaner).  As mentioned in my comment to his answer, it seems like there has got to be a way to reference it somehow...I mean JS needs a reference in order to make method chaining possible in the first place right?

Comment: jQuery method chaining is accomplished by returning the jQuery object from the `$()` method (and most other jQuery methods called subsequently), so that's where the reference comes from in that case. What you're asking about would be a feature in JavaScript to refer to the object on which a method was called.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#randomString').val(escape(this));
```

This does not get the object you want. It is effectively the equivalent of doing this:

```
var foo = escape(this);
$('#randomString').val(foo);
```

`this` only means something different when you start a new scope with a function definition.

jQuery does offer this kind of functionality with a callback option:

```
$('#randomString').val(function (idx, oldVal) {
    return escape(oldVal);
});
```

The second parameter is the current value of the element; the return value sets a new value for the element.

Comment: ah okay, this is a bit more than a simple "this"..seems like there should be something more elegant and simple to refer to the most immediate object selected, but I guess this is probably as good as it gets

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$(document.ready(function () {

  $('#encode').click(function() {
    var $randomString =  $('#randomString');
    $randomString.val(escape($randomString.val()));
  });
  $('#decode').click(function() {
    var $randomString =  $('#randomString');
    $randomString.val(unescape($randomString.val()));
  });     
});
```

Comment: For the purposes of my example code, this is actually more code, but I guess ultimately this is probably what I'm looking for, or the closest to it.  I still think there could (or should) be a way to $([selector]).something([referencetoselector]) though... I mean that's the whole point of chaining stuff...SOMEWHERE there's got to be a reference for js to use, otherwise chaining methods wouldn't be possible!

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a little generic:

```
$.fn.applyVal = function(func) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).val( func( $(this).val() ) );
    });
};
```

Then the following call is enough:

```
$('#randomString').applyVal(escape);
```

Comment: If you want to make it generic, you should probably handle the circumstance where more than one element has been selected.

Comment: @lonesomeday: You're correct, although .val also only works on the first element.